# Entry font size Xamarin.Forms iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms

I am using xamarin forms and I want different font sizes for different platforms, for example i want my Android entries to have FontSize 14, and in iOS I want them to be FontSize 12, I can do it programatically with the code below, but is there any way to do it in XAML?

```
 if (Device.OS == TargetPlatform.iOS)
        {
            Entry.FontSize = 12;

        }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<Entry>
  <Entry.FontSize>
    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double"
      iOS="20"
      Android="25" />
  </Entry.FontSize>
</Entry>
```